# Defining interface for a function that uses typeof value for generic types

Tags: typescript

I am creating a factory that instantiates an object without losing any type inference.

Object classes that are to be instantiated are defined in a keyed collection:

```
abstract class Model { }

class Player extends Model {
    a: string;

    constructor(a: string) {
        super();

        this.a = a;
    }

    say() {
        console.log(this.a)
    }
}

class OtherModel extends Model {}

enum ModelType {
    Player,
    OtherModel
}

const Models = {
    [ModelType.Player]: Player,
    [ModelType.OtherModel]: OtherModel
};
```

Finally the factory I came up with is defined like so:

```
class ModelFactory implements IFactory {
    instantiate<T extends keyof typeof Models>(type: T, ...params: ConstructorParameters<typeof Models[T]>): InstanceType<typeof Models[T]> {
        if (Models) {
            const ModelRef = Models[type] as new (...params: any[]) => InstanceType<typeof Models[T]>;

            if (!ModelRef) {
                throw new Error(`Model for '${ModelType[type]}' was not found.`);
            }

            return new ModelRef(...params);
        }

        throw new Error("No models are registered");
    }
}
```

This works pretty well, as it's able to infer constructor properties as well as the return type on compile-time. The problem I'm having is defining the interface for the factory. Since I am getting the type of model collection defined above, I can't come up with way to define an abstract instantiate() signature.

I've created a [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=58&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgewCYFNkEBvBAXwCgKU0MAFVAT3ygXwA8J8A7XDHAkWIUEohMABcCSFACW3AOYBuEWJBSZ85VTFJs3GQFd42KAApJ06FoA0CdVbmKAlCVW7RYQwAcWZ5yruHhAAFrJgAHTACAC84ioeYqHhESCx9glilEFgwIz+bomisPpg2Mj4EcjYCmYABgAkxMmRwGQITS2pZHXOQZTZNOgIAPKhLAKEbJw8fFh4U8K6JQbQxhCmBUtFXr7mAf0U2TyGALbzggAqjL6FYgCqvPgAZvL4uDZBDHksn7pjIQmC2QRyoK0gF0IGDi21EAG1Jshrr4It9mFAALpSNG-III4HIyoAoGCLGjcZQRFHQLyLhQZ5wfAIACSADE4BsoIwSOQwahhoj2SYuQhZKdvBVTjwIBg2RzTNzYaLVsBuBBZMAuAAeS7TLi8DAAa3wjGwzwQEBu+DNkOQYAAfGZLb4pJc7BEPd5gDBTmApABhUprYV0b3AKV0sBa53W82IsBwy4Y+3OKTMlXcWD4QnRq02+OJ5N3RKyc1meOuJVFPSrW0AJRe6QLMYx4gw3HwAHcEGYPREvT6-eJuIw4RjXDF7SyM1mczH88CE0n7YFq7pSz2AISIhvPStBNdJEJQbDdjvdgCiUBP5jqiIQz1MCAA5E1EYS4S2yM+EJ20AhuGwRBH0MXgIl6TJD0oQ9RAPIooHwCBDCgbgAK7esXl7T0w19A5q2yatQhPM90KvG8zAAIgAOWwBBTkXcQEIQBCFHCOl3govCslBaggzo4EhU5bk4nPW1BIVfwVHBRAJR+Vg4nowRxK5CJ5EgVV1U1fBywJK1USYX4X2AZ87GfEBnwOChZPRCJcnyA4gA) to illustrate the problem better.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, you need `IFactory` to be generic and then `class ModelFactory extends IFactory<typeof Models>`.  In that case `IFactory` can be defined like `interface IFactory<M extends Record<keyof M, new (...args: any) => any>> { instantiate<K extends keyof M>(type: K, ...params: ConstructorParameters<M[K]>): InstanceType<M[K]> }`.  Does that work for you?  If so, I'll write up an answer. If not, can you elaborate on your requirements?    Good luck.

Comment: @jcalz Yes! That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you wanted was for `IFactory` to have an `instantiate` method that works for exactly the constructors in the `Models` object, then you could just give it the same signature as the corresponding method in `ModelFactory` and be done.

Presumably though you want something that, for a *given* object whose values are constructors, has a *corresponding* `instantiate` method that works for that object.  If so, then you should make `IFactory` into a [generic](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) interface which depends on the type of the constructor object.  Here's how I'd write it:

```
interface IFactory<M extends Record<keyof M, new (...args: any) => any>> {
    instantiate<K extends keyof M>(
        type: K,
        ...params: ConstructorParameters<M[K]>
    ): InstanceType<M[K]>
}
```

In this code, `M` takes the place of `typeof Models`, and is [constrained](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to an object type whose values are constructors.

Then you can just say that `ModelFactory implements IFactory<typeof Models>`:

```
class ModelFactory implements IFactory<typeof Models> {
    instantiate<T extends keyof typeof Models>(type: T, ...params: ConstructorParameters<typeof Models[T]>): InstanceType<typeof Models[T]> {
        if (Models) {
            const ModelRef = Models[type] as new (...params: any[]) => InstanceType<typeof Models[T]>;

            if (!ModelRef) {
                throw new Error(`Model for '${ModelType[type]}' was not found.`);
            }

            return new ModelRef(...params);
        }

        throw new Error("No models are registered");
    }
}
```

and presumably a different factory would be declared to implement `IFactory<typeof somethingElse>` where `somethingElse` is a different object holding different constructors.

---

Also note that you could make the whole factory class generic like this:

```
class GenericModelFactory<
    M extends Record<keyof M, new (...args: any) => any>
    > implements IFactory<M> {
    constructor(public models: M) {

    }
    instantiate<K extends keyof M>(
        type: K,
        ...params: ConstructorParameters<M[K]>
    ): InstanceType<M[K]> {
        const ModelRef = this.models[type] as
            new (...params: ConstructorParameters<M[K]>) => InstanceType<M[K]>;
        return new ModelRef(...params);

    }
}    

const modelFactory2 = new GenericModelFactory(Models);
const player2 = modelFactory2.instantiate(ModelType.Player, 'a', 'b');
player2.say();
```

That puts the constructor-holding object as a property of the factory class itself, so you can reuse the same factory class instead of making new ones for each set of model constructors.  It all depends on your use case which way you want to go.

---

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgewCYFNkEBvBAXwQChKU0MAFVAT3ygXwA8J8A7XDHASLFKCMQmAAuBJCgBLHgHMA3KPEhpshSurik2HrICu8bFAAUUmdG0AaBBuvylAShJq9YsEYAOrcy6qHp4QABZyYAB0wAgAvBKqnuJhEZEgcQ6J4mS64mDATAHuSWKwBmDYyPiRyNiK5gAGACTEKVHAFC1taWQNLsE5OTSo6AgA8mGsgoTsXLz8WHgzInplhtAmEGZFKyXefhaBA5RDvEYAtotCACpMfsXiAKp8+ABmCvi4tsGMBazfegmoSmS2QJ2oa0gV0IGHiuzEAG1pshbn5Ir8WFAALrSDH-YJI0Go6pAkFCHHjSZQZEnIIKbhQV5wfAIACSADE4FsoEwADyYWbcPgYABK+DKUFwvIA1vgmNhXlh7Dx8AB3BDmSJa4BQRRgaTAHhMNyxAB8EiNpvN8IQCkghogcmA3F5AGlBfMMLL5YrMKbzME9BA7vhpK6ASUtZEfDrgOd9QgAMLlDamKD0WPnfAMsD8hGurGm4IuaSs9aG2D4Yl5gtFoa0UbIzlppi284+KpZngQDAcrlmPnBvwK6HIMDW4J2iAOp0u64e4UIb0jof4EfI8fmVfSa72KMxmDx6TJ9ZQTZmDOH7OsXOr9egsAI66Fkts8s8SvVu++h9PwsPJI5EVcwNzcG0Sn0dZRzFRV4g3BFVyxCQMBVdVNS1A84wTQ0mARLETXNMt7Q-KsQ15b9R0fZ9TSCCC9CAjUAEJkRgsDAzosQwigbB1VQhAAFEoG4iwGmRBBXjMBAAHIWmRYkEJDLEyCkhBVTQBAeGwRAJKMPhIj6LIOKGDixCgbMjCgHgNLVaC3nQ6NMzAI4IOMkouJ46z1UE4TzAAIgAOWwBBzgfCQzIQMzFAiBlPl85zsnBCEU2C0Fm25Vt4j4pt+x5AJVEhRAOz+Nh4hCoQ0oHSIpxnZ18BAokQ3RZh-mk4ApPsKSQCko5KCKzFInyQoeohEYMAAcV4Vg5FgbKW15YIBU4IUFjFCUpWXX1lRs+ydT1A0jQIi0mCLPRzTkdtO14Hs2Qqnl+QnVYUzPNNzB8IwQGQaaUqEBNMDY456PfR1ardBcFg2rB-XYziQzDCMkn3Rzjye8900za8oFzTB80LYtS3fT8yOx2sAM8ArbNghBujKmEFL8JC0Ghzw+PszCjyTFG00vOMMaxnHTUOojpxI6ticLQzPDMiALKsrLQRg1nHJ6vRBmoGhkpp5BbqYAAmDI+ImlV5Bm1KcsKUD8uSvrWD10rTZbHWqqB2c6rkxq8SgDq2o6rqjmtqBHcGvLKCAA)